# How to import JTable values in Excel?

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

I am trying to load `JTable` value in excel sheet but it is giving null pointer exception. Now when I try to insert that data using break after for loop of j it will insert it into excel but Other it gives Null Pointer Exception.

Below is the code:

```
 private void writeToExcel() {
        XSSFWorkbook ws = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet wb = ws.createSheet();
        XSSFRow row = wb.createRow(0);;
        XSSFCell cell = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < datatypetable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        int ColNum = 0;
        row = wb.createRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < datatypetable.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            cell = wb.getRow(i).getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            if (cell == null) {
                System.out.println("Cell Project is: " + cell.toString());  
                cell = row.createCell(ColNum);
                cell.setCellValue(datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
            } else {
                //cell = row.createCell(j);  
                System.out.println("Cell Object is: " + cell.toString());  
                System.out.println(datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                **cell.setCellValue(datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString());**
            }
            ColNum++;
        }

    }    

        //Write Excel to file System
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(workingDir + File.separator + "First" + ".xls");
            ws.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataEntryArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataEntryArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Error in the code is in line **cell.setCellValue(datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString());** -

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.boolment.dataentry.DataEntryArea.writeToExcel(DataEntryArea.java:1243)
        at com.boolment.dataentry.DataEntryArea.jButton6ActionPerformed(DataEntryArea.java:1263)
        at com.boolment.dataentry.DataEntryArea.access$2000(DataEntryArea.java:87)
        at com.boolment.dataentry.DataEntryArea$23.actionPerformed(DataEntryArea.java:717)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I know that there is one solution of this code and I have also tried that but still it's not working. and how can I solve that?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"I know that there is one solution of this code and I have also tried that but still it's not working"* What? A solution isn't a solution unless it works!

Comment: Add to the mcve the printout of the full error message (NullPointerException stacktrace). It should tell you which line caused the NPE. mark this line with a comment in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of getting null pointer exception. I was getting error due to this `datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString()` as some value is table may be null and when they were null it was getting an error NullPointerException.

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatypetable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                int ColNum = 0;
                row = wb.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < datatypetable.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    cell = wb.getRow(i).getCell(ColNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    String item1 = null;
                    if (datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j) != null) {
                        cell.setCellValue(datatypetable.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(item1);
                    }
                    ColNum++;
                }


   }
```

I have not provide whole code as the above code will be same as whatI have asked. The only changes are to be made in this for loop.
Hope my answer helps anyone.